# Unable to group by results as per required format in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL query

```
select fact as [fact], [report.id] from #TEMP
order by [report.id]
```

> Output:- (8 rows)

[image]

But my expected result is:

[image]

I know I would need to use group by report.id but it needs aggregate function usage. I am across **string_agg()** function. But I have restriction on SQL server 2016 which does not supports this function.

Please can anyone help me get the results.

Comment: What you posted won't produce JSON.  Post the *actual* query you used.

Comment: Are you storing JSON data in your database, or are you actually using something else to create the above? `STRING_AGG` (or `FOR XML PATH`) won't help you get the result you want above with the data you've show us in  that image if you are storing JSON data.

Comment: You can shape query results, convert them to JSON, even created nested JSON results, using the correct FOR JSON syntax. Instead of trying to concatenate strings, explain what you actually try to do. It's probably a lot easier than generating strings and concatenating then

Comment: Never mind the obvious question - why do that on the *server*?

Answer (score 0):

I would use STUFF e.g.

```
create table #test1 (val1 varchar(50),val2 numeric)

INSERT INTO #test1 VALUES('apple',1)
INSERT INTO #test1 VALUES('pinapple',1)
INSERT INTO #test1 VALUES('cucumber',2)
INSERT INTO #test1 VALUES('pickles',2)
INSERT INTO #test1 VALUES('orange',3)
INSERT INTO #test1 VALUES('mango',4)
INSERT INTO #test1 VALUES('lemon',23)

SELECT (STUFF((SELECT ', ' + val1 FROM #test1 WHERE val2 = B.val2 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')) AS StringValue
    , B.val2
from #test1 as B
group by B.val2
```